# How to view Openstack Swift objects in web browser

Tags: ubuntu, openstack-swift

I have created a VM with openstack swift running and I have created a container with some objects. In theory, the URL to each object should be `http://<IP_ADDRESS>:8080/v1/AUTH_test/images/test.txt`. However this directory does not exist so this URL will never be found.

Any ideas on how to view the objects that are stored in a container on a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Swift responds to REST methods. You have to first get a authentication token from keystone and make a GET request with the header to get an xml or json response containing the object name and the related info.

Check the OpenStack API reference doc for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You try to access the objects with your browser, but you do need an authentication token, which is not send by the browser by default.

You could use a webapp called swiftbrowser, if you want to browse your files with your webbrowser: https://github.com/cschwede/django-swiftbrowser

The swiftbrowser is a webapp, which also handles authentication (which you need to access the objects) and supports also the generation of temporary urls und form uploads.

Comment: Do not post link-only answers. Post some part of the link in the answer itself.